# Android webview displaying differently when from file instead of from online

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am trying to save the HTML from a webpage into a file so if my app is opened and no internet is available then the webview loads from a file instead. Here is my debugging code - the first time the view is created it downloads the file. The second time onwards it opens the files

```
WebView cwebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.aboutWebview);
    if(loadedLatest) {
        cwebView.loadData(FileUtils.read(Values.aboutWebviewOfflineFile,getContext()),"text/html", "UTF-8");
        cwebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //cwebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }else {
        cwebView.loadUrl(Values.aboutPageURL);
        new GetWebviewContents(getContext()).execute(Values.aboutPageURL, Values.aboutWebviewOfflineFile) //Saves the HTML to a file;
        loadedLatest = true;
    }
```

The HTML download and file seem to be working correctly however the webview looks completely different when from online and when from the file - it is much narrower and images overlap. I have tried using .loadurl(File...) and it has the same effect. Enabling Javascript makes no difference.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?
Thanks

Comment: It sounds like it's a missing CSS problem. Is it possible?

Comment: I believe the HTML may contain some JS and some CSS - it's from an online builder so I'm not totally familiar with how it works. If that was the case do you know of a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but it could be the issue of Cross-Origin blocking by the WebView. To verify that this is the issue, open the same webpage that you saved on your app, on your laptop or desktop, and save it on your disk. Then try to open that saved page and see the Javascript console on your's browser Developer Tools and see if it shows any Cross-Origin access restriction errors.